# Saving game progress files at path /storage/emulated/0/namefolder is this really allowed to do?

Tags: android, file, unity-game-engine, path, save

I'm developing a game in Unity for android and I am using a standard different folder Application path.**persistentDataPath** to save my game progress, coins etc. I'm doing this because if anyone uninstall the game, the files were protected and game progress will not be lost, as the **Application.persistentDataPath** folder files are deleted.

I can write and read the game progress in different folders, but my question is: is this really allowed us to do? Infringes any use policy? Or it may be harmful in any way?

Comment: Yes that is allowed. But your question contains a hard coded path. Do not use hard coded paths. You better ask if you can use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` for it. It delivers a path which is different among devices.

Comment: Application.persistentDataPath + "/../../namefolder/" +  filename    possible?

Comment: What do you mean with `Application.persistentDataPath` ?. I told you to use getExternalSorageDirectory(). React on that please.

Answer (score 0):

yes android device allows to read and write the data from external storage. your requirement also if game is deleted,but game state should not lost. so you should write the data in external storage (not in sd card, because sd card may be removed after some days also).

1. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() //it returns the root Directory.
2. Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()// it returns the specific directory
3. If you write in the External Storage, It will be accessed by other apps also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. No it does not infringe on any policy unless you try to modify other files not related to your app, or create lots of useless files that take up lots of memory for no purpose.

You should make sure that the user can't access the file and modify, or delete it, also when the user wants to uninstall the app, there won't be any leftovers files.

Comment: `make sure that the user can't access the file and modify, or delete it,`. Why? The user can. Thats ok. Dont bother. `when the user wants to uninstall the app, there won't be any leftovers files.`. Nonsense. OP asked specially for a place where files survive uninstall.

Comment: Seems  I misunderstood the question.